# Adding Unicode UTF8 to email

Tags: php, email, unicode, utf-8

Can anyone help me please how to add a utf-8 Unicode for these characters?

> žýáťčšľľzŽŘ

Now the email looks like this

> Dostali ste novÃº sprÃ¡vu.  Tu sÃº podrobnosti:  JmÃ©no: tÃ¡r 
>   Tel.ÄÃ­slo: 4996611

```
<?php

$EmailFrom = "...";
$EmailTo = "mail@mail";
$Subject = "Zpráva s ";
$name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
$phone = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['phone'])); 
$email = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
$message = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

// validation
$validationOK=true;
if (!$validationOK) {
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
  exit;
}

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Tel: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

// send email 
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>");

// redirect to success page 
if ($success){
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=contactthanks.php\">";
}
else{
  print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=error.htm\">";
}
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)  about UTF-8 header or whatever the encoding you have? Did you consider using an already made mail class like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got two ambiguous parts of your script where character-sets aren't being considered. It's possible your form isn't sending UTF-8 or it's possible you're sending UTF-8 in your email but the client is expecting a different encoding.

1. I assume you're using a form to post data. Ensure it's set to send UTF-8 from the browser. The strings will now be UTF-8 encoded.

   ```
   <form action="myform" accept-charset="UTF-8">
   ```
2. You need to add character set and transfer encoding headers to the email header:

   ```
   $success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From: <$EmailFrom>\r\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit");
   ```

BTW, a faster way to redirect the user is to set the `Location` header in the response. Use:

```
header('Location: contactthanks.php')
```